# Python : Correct way to strip <p> and </p> from string?

Tags: python, string

I want to strip out `<p>` and `</p>` from a string (lets say `s`).

Right now I am doing this :

```
s.strip('"<p>""</p>"')
```

I am not really sure if what I am doing is correct, but this has been effective enough with most of the strings that I have used.

Except, I still get the following string : `Here goes..</p>`

Is there any other effective way to strip? It does not need to fast or efficient. I need something effective that get's the work done.

#### Test Case

Let's say:
`s="<p>Here goes..</p>"`

After performing the necessary operations on `s`, `print s` should give :
`Here goes..`

Comment: First add some test cases to the question, with input and desired output.

Comment: @sorin - added. Hope this is ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're not trying to sanitise XML/HTML the following will work:

```
s = s.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '')
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're dealing with a lot of HTML/XML, you might want to use a parser to easily and safely manipulate it instead of using basic string manipulation functions. I really like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for this kind of work. It works with invalid markup and has a really elegant API.

In your example, you could use it like this:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>hello world</p>')
>>> soup.text
u'hello world'
```

Comment: +1 For BeautifulSoup! I really like it too. But I am not working with a lot of tags and I did not want to use a different module for just one string that may or may not have html tags. Simple string manipulation get's the job done, here.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to strip the whole all characters present in the `"<p>""</p>"` string from your values. `strip` treats this value as a *set*, it'll remove any `"`, `<`, `p`, `/`, or `>` from your string.

```
>>> s = 'Here goes "/p>'
>>> s.strip('"<p>""</p>"')
'Here goes '
```

So, using `strip` (and `rstrip` and `lstrip`) is only suitable if you want to remove sets of characters, not a multi-character string as a whole.

If you want to remove `<p>` from the start and `</p>` from the end, you could use the following:

```
if s.startswith('<p>'):
     s = s[3:]
if s.endswith('</p>'):
     s = s[:-4]
```

If you need to remove these from elsewhere in the string, you need to use `s.replace`:

```
s.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '')
```

or you could look into regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I was really confused about the `.strip` operation (along with it's variants).

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex for that, just an import and one line:

```
>>> import re
>>> s="text<p>text</p>text"
>>> re.sub("</?p>","",s)
'texttexttext'
```

The reason of `split("</p>")`'s fail is trying to strip `<`,`/`,`p` or `>`; not `</p>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
s="<p>Here goes..</p>"
s = s.lstrip("<p>")
s = s.rstrip("</p>").strip('.')
```